# Regression taget definition of target value range

Tags: r, regression, data-mining, r-caret

Is it possible to define a target value range for predictions using the `caret` package?

I am trying to create a prediction model with `caret`.

The dataset I use to train the model is `train` and currently I am testing with `method="lm"`.

My code is similar to this:

```
fit <- train(target ~ val1 + val2 + val3, method="lm", data=train)
```

I do get predictions, but some of them are out of the possible value range. Only values in the range [0,1] are possible.

Comment: method `lm` is not appropriate for the value range `0-1` you probably need `glm` with  `family = "binomial"`. Are you predicting probabilities?

Comment: Yes, I am predicting probabilities. Thank you, I will try glm.

Comment: Please make the outcome a factor that _doesn't_ use "0"/"1" levels. Use a proper encoding for qualitative data.

Comment: I think you missunderstand me. I am trying to predict values between 0 percent and 100 percent. I dont want a binary result.

Comment: Is there a list of caret methods which I can use for range 0 to 1?

Comment: What is your target `variable`? could you post an example of it? is it a continuous numeric from the range `0 - 1`. If so you will have a bit of a problem finding the right implementation. You can train any regression type model and than transform the output using softprob. However classification models probably have a more suitable loss function for the type of model you would like to fit. However I am not aware of any that have this type of behavior out of the box. They are usually made for cases when the target variable is categorical.

Comment: @lmo in the title, should it be _Regression target_ or _Regression caret_?